# How to transfer images through REST API

Tags: android, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a mobile application which needs to display images which will be sent to it via REST API. How do I tranfser images ove the API? I am developing a ASP.net Web API using C#.

I tried converting image to base64 then send it though API to the mobile device, but this seems to take a lot of time as I have to send large number of images to my mobile device in one run.

I need to send image file along with some other data through the API to mobile device and a Phonegap android will then save it in local db for further use.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can generate public links to the images from your specialized data store (something like `Amazon S3` or `Azure Blob Storage`) and then only send links over the `API`.

Comment: But at the mobile app side I do not want to access the images from web, as app is supposed to work even offline(without internet)

Comment: So then you can have a local cache store for your images. But first time you will have to fetch!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sent the images alongside other data in one request using base64 is the best way.

You could think of using gzip to compress the image data to reduce the size. An other way would be to send the images in a reduced size to your android client alonside with a URL to a fully sized image. This enables you to show you results quickly to the user and then load the large images in a background task from the server and replace the small ones in the database.

Comment: Android will not have access to inetnet all the time. Only during the first run of the app or whenever user wants to update the data(provided there's internet connectivity..), the api will be called which will load/update the data from mobile local database. So loading the fully sized image in background will not work. :-(

Comment: Then there is no real alternative to load all images at once. As I said you can compress the images or use JPEGs with a lower quality/higher compression to reduce the file sizes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send image or a file through REST Api then it should be implement through Multipart request.
Please refer [here](http://www.jayway.com/2011/09/15/multipart-form-data-file-uploading-made-simple-with-rest-assured/) how it make your work easy.

You can also use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for creating multipart request.

Comment: I am building the API in MVC.

Comment: MVC for Model View Controller? or something else?

Comment: Yes. Model view controller Web API in ASP.net

Comment: I don't know much about ASP .net but I am sure it will also have the multipart support.

Comment: Please refer the link    http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/125/asp-net-mvc-uploading-and-downloading-files